# sympy: canonicalise a linear equality with constant on right hand side

Tags: python, math, sympy

I am trying to find a decent way (with sympy) to canonicalise a linear equality with the constant on the right hand side. For example:

```
x + 1 = y
```

becomes:

```
x - y = -1
```

This is my rather hacky solution:

```
def canonical_linear(f):
""" canonicalise a linear equality """

    lhs = f.lhs - f.rhs
    const_l = [ x for x in lhs.as_ordered_terms() if x.is_number ]

    if len(const_l) == 0:
        const = 0
    elif len(const_l) == 1:
        const = const_l[0]
    else:
        raise NotImplementedError("SHIT")

    return sympy.Eq(lhs - const, -const)
```

Can this be improved? Cheers?

Comment: Is this just for printing and aesthetics or is it a part of solving a bigger problem?

Comment: It's to pass to a linear solver

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is from the source code for the `solve` routine in SymPy:

```
1262         if all(p.is_linear for p in polys):
1263             n, m = len(polys), len(symbols)
1264             matrix = zeros(n, m + 1)
1265 
1266             for i, poly in enumerate(polys):
1267                 for monom, coeff in poly.terms():
1268                     try:
1269                         j = list(monom).index(1)
1270                         matrix[i, j] = coeff
1271                     except ValueError:
1272                         matrix[i, m] = -coeff
1273 
1274             # returns a dictionary ({symbols: values}) or None
1275             result = solve_linear_system(matrix, *symbols, **flags)
```

It transforms each equation into a polynomial (`Poly` is a class in SymPy for efficient work with polynomials) and if the polynomial is linear it traverses it in order to construct a matrix to be solved (the last column is the free coefficient).

The code above does not show the transformation into polynomials. The polynomials are in `polys` and the free symbols are in `symbols`.

Comment: By the way it makes sense to factor this piece of code out in a dedicated routine. I will update this answer if we decide to do it.

Comment: Also, while I have a sympy developer's attention, can i draw you attention to this (unrelated) bug: http://code.google.com/p/sympy/issues/detail?id=1625 . This drives me crazy.

Comment: A possible solution is here: https://github.com/sympy/sympy/pull/1378 We can continue the discussion there.